# Copying Allies with Shapeshifter

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I control a [Renegade Doppelganger](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRenegade%20Doppelganger%5d) and I play [Umara Raptor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUmara%20Raptor%5d) and choose for Renegade Doppleganger to copy it, would the Renegade Doppleganger get the +1/+1 counter?

Comment: Are you asking about the 'when Umara Raptor enters the battlefield' part, or the 'when another Ally enters the battlefield' part of the ability? Since the first one is a duplicate of the one marked, but the second one would have a different reason (the answer is still no though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  This is covered in the [rulings for Renegade Doppelganger](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=193582):

> If Renegade Doppelganger becomes a copy of another creature, that doesn’t count as having a creature enter the battlefield. Renegade Doppelganger was already on the battlefield; it only changed its characteristics. **If Renegade Doppelganger gains any enters-the-battlefield triggered abilities, they won’t do anything.** The same is true of any “as [this creature] enters the battlefield” or “[this creature] enters the battlefield with” abilities.

Answer (score 1):

**No,**

Your renegade doppelganger will become an Umara raptor.
but renegade doppleganger is not a Umara Raptor when Umara Raptor entered the battlefield and thus will not recieve a +1/+1 counter.

See following explanation:

Umara Raptor enters the battlefield:2 abilities will trigger

- Umara raptor will put a +1/+1 counter on itself.
- Renegade Doppelganger becomes a copy of Umara Raptor

There are currently no other "when ... enters the battlefield abilities present"

Both abilities will resolve.
Umara Raptor is already on the battlefield after this.

---

EDIT: Note that Umara Raptors trigger can be split into 2 parts:

1. **Whenever Umara Raptor enters the battlefield** (see BJ Myers answer, the Renegade Doppelganger never enters the battlefield because of his cloning ability)
2. **or another Ally enters the battlefield under your control** (adressed in this answer)

Comment: So if I played two uma raptors and compied the first one withRenegade would he get a +1/+1 when the second entered

Comment: That is correct.